# Xcode 11 Create Remote Git Repositories but showing "Loading account owners" never ends

Tags: xcode11, remote-repository

I have an existing Xcode project downloaded from Apple Developer web site and it was not under source control. So I first add it to local Git by running "git init". Then I open the project and try to add it to my GitHub repository. After clicking "Create XXXX remote", the dialog shows "Loading account owners..." and it never ends. Anyone knows how to resolve it?

[Xcode showing Loading account owners and never end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgqDG.jpg)

Comment: This question should have been asked on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

You must setup your repo account first in Xcode.  Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts.  Click the plus at the bottom of the left pane and select the appropriate account to add (i.e. GitHub).  Enter your credentials and they will be verified.  Return to the remote repo flow and your account will now display in the Accounts drop-down.